# C++: Speed of game and Networking

Tags: c++, networking, client-server, timedelta, delta

I have a question regarding delta time to make my game run framerate independent in a multiplayer setting.

Will using the delta result in the same speed for every client? Or should the clients receive the delta used by the server and use that to make the game run at the same speed?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use a fixed amount of `ticks` per time (e.g. 30 ticks per second). (Only) in these ticks any game objects are updated. For Rendering you interpolate between the ticks.

How synchronization works is largely dependen on a number of factors. Client and Server can synchronize in each tick through some kind or barrier-mechanism, or the server sends updates on each tick and the clients don't do ticks themselves at all. Of course there are a lot more possibilities, but this should give you a start, I hope